# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, material-design

I'm using my app AppCompat for work with material-design. Running the app fails before displaying the following error in the onCreate of MainActivity class, which inherits from AppCompactActivity:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11
```

Currently my app also uses Facebook SDK and Google Play Service. I searched for a solution and I find no work :(. Someone who can help I thank him. I leave the complete error log.

**PD:** I'm using eclipse.

```
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589): Process: com.tauro.videochat, PID: 23589
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:414)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at com.tauro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**Edition:**

Logcat full

```
05-20 13:51:42.944: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7>
05-20 13:51:42.945: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7>
05-20 13:51:42.945: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11>
05-20 13:51:42.946: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11>
05-20 13:51:42.947: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7>
05-20 13:51:42.947: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11>
05-20 13:51:42.948: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7>
05-20 13:51:42.948: I/art(23589): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11>
05-20 13:51:42.949: D/AndroidRuntime(23589): Shutting down VM
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589): Process: com.tauro.videochat, PID: 23589
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:414)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at com.tauro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-20 13:51:46.039: E/AndroidRuntime(23589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Logcat is incomplete i guess

Comment: that's all it shows the logcat

Comment: on emulator or just on smartphone ? what's your smartphone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same exact error!  It gives you no clear cause to the problem either.  What a pain it was.  I spent an entire day trying to figure out the fix for it.  Here's what I found -- Google Play services is a massive code base.  With all the other generic libraries that I used I hit the dex limit of 65k methods.  This was causing the error that I had (and maybe yours too).

Some tips to bring it down:

1. Selectively choose which Google Play services you want to use. 
   [Directions here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?utm_campaign=dex-1214)
2. If that doesn't work, try multidexing your application.  [Directions here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).  Note:  If you run into issues, try extending
   MultiDexApplication instead of Application.
3. Clean the project, restart Eclipse, and/or restart your computer.  This has fixed similar issues when it wasn't related to the dex issues above.

Answer (score 0):

Add compatibility-v4 v21 into your build.

I added it as a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
    <version>22.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```